# Google Cloud Platform : increase the quota above the default

Tags: google-maps, cloud, platform, quota

I'd like to increase the quota for access to my APIs.

Looking around, I found [this link](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#managing_your_quota),
but the information does not satisfy my needs.

Google Cloud Platform limits me with very low numbers, and when trying to increase the quotas in specific ones that I desire, I am not allowed, I am asked to click on

[image: IMAGE THAT WILL EXPLAIN BETTER WHAT I AM FEELING DIFFICULTY.]

"... For values above 2,400, sign up for a higher quota" and click to go to this page https://cloud.google.com/contact/

On this page I have no specific form for this service or guidance.

My account is an upgrade account - with billing possible.
how can I have this increase - above the number set by google, to meet my needs?

Answer (score 0):

To address this kind of issues, please file a support case via https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support in order to open personalized communication channel.

This is the correct channel for these kind of queries as it needs account investigation.